# What does "read above a fourth-grade level" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the English horror movie "Freddy Vs Jason", Lori asks Linderman about his clothes:

> Lori: What happened to your clothes?
>
> Linderman: Oh, this. I was playing a drinking game with some of the
>   lower primates and I guess I'm penalized for my ability to **read
>   above a fourth-grade level**.

Situation: Linderman forced to drink beer at a party, and some of the beer got on his clothes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Fourth Grade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_grade) (also called Grade Four or Year five in Britain) is a term used to refer to a year of elementary education in some countries. In North America, the fourth grade is the fifth school year of elementary school. Students are usually 9–10 years old, depending on their birthday. It is a part of elementary school, a school providing instruction for young pupils, comprising traditionally of grades K-6.
>   (Wikipedia)

The "fourth grade reading level" is the level of literacy expected of fourth graders. Since he can read above this level, he can read better than a fourth grader.  This is a low standard for an adult. It's a further insult to the "lower primates".